# Show Date with st,nd,rd in superscript in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Is there any way in which we can have the Sysdate like **23rd September,2020**  , **'rd'** in superscript.
I tried this query:
**select to_char(sysdate,'ddth Month,YYYY','NLS_DATE_language=American') from dual;**
which gives me the result as **23rd September,2020**  but what I want is the **'rd'** in superscript.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is such thing, but since you are converting it to a string anyway you might want to concatenate

```
select upper(to_char(sysdate, 'ddth')) || ' ' || to_char(sysdate, 'Month,YYYY','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=American') from dual
```

This gives me "23RD September,2020"

Comment: Why concatenate?

Comment: Hi @TonyAndrews otherwise month name will be in superscript as well. Like "23RD SEPTEMBER" and Ayushya asks for "rd" to be in superscript only. Like "23RD September"